# EF Linq- Dynamic Lambda expression trees

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a generic repository that uses generic expressions for returning data from Entity Framework Core.

```
public async Task<T2> GetFieldsAsync<T2>(Expression<Func<T, T2>> expression)
  {
            return await context.Set<T>()
                                .Select(expression)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
  }
```

Now if I want to select specific fields, at compile time I can write the following statement:

```
var test = await _repositoryBase.GetFieldsAsync(x => new { x.Id, x.Name });
```

I want to be able to do above at run time instead. I can create an expression at run time that returns a single parameter as follows:

```
var expression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Ingredient), "ingr");
var param1 = Expression.Property(expression, "Id");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Ingredient, Guid>>(param1, expression);
var test = await _repositoryBase.GetFieldsAsync(lambda);
```

The above lambda only returns a single property from the Ingredient class. **Is it possible to create a run time lambda that returns an anonymous object using expression trees?** I.e.

```
x => new { x.Id, x.Name }
```

Note that users might request different fields (e.g. Name, Description, DateCreated, etc.) so need to dynamically create the lambda expression.

I know I can use https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core to pass in strings to select statements via its built-in IQueryable extension methods. I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically select specific fields at run time via a list of fields passed in by the user.

---

Currently, my approach is to get all properties of the class from the database, and use an ExpandoObject to only select the fields that user requests. The issue here is that although it works, I am returning more data from the database than is required. I'd like to avoid this by only selecting the required data.

```
//user did not provide any fields so include all fields
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
     {
         myPropertyInfoList.AddRange(typeProperties);
     }
    else
      {
        foreach (var item in fields)
        {
            myPropertyInfoList.Add(type.GetProperty(item, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance));
        }

    var expandoObj = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (var item in myPropertyInfoList)
        {
            expandoObj.Add(item.Name, item.GetValue(ingrView));
        }
```

Comment: It is possible, but extremely difficult. This may be one of the only cases where it is worthwhile (assuming you have extremely large rows and lots of them). Do you really expect to see a performance improvement by narrowing the returned data?

Comment: Another possibility is using [LINQ Dynamic Query](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) which allows you to pass a string as an argument to `Select` that can reduce your returned values.

Comment: @NetMage I've already tested using Linq dynamic query library to pass in the fields via a string and it works. I wanted to see if I could remove a dependency on that library as all I really need is the ability to select specific fields. I already paginate data so I am not selecting a large amount of data but still I wanted to see if it was possible via expression trees

Comment: It is possible, but it requires a fair amount of code. I'll provide a (possibly even working) sample.

Comment: @NetMage That would be much appreciated if you could and explain some of the concepts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified anonymous type creator. It uses public fields instead of building properties, it has no methods implemented (it gets a default constructor).

First, a simple extension method I use later:

```
public static class StringExt {
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string sep) => String.Join(sep, strings);    
}
```

Here, the code to create a new anonymous type from a `Dictionary<string,Type>` that describes the anonymous type. A generic type with type parameters for the type of every field (property) is generated and then fixed to the actual types being used - which is how the C# compiler generates anonymous types. This code creates (once) a dynamic Assembly and Module, then adds new types as needed. It uses a cache to (attempt) to prevent creating the same type more than once.

```
public static class AnonymousExt {
    private static readonly CustomAttributeBuilder CompilerGeneratedAttributeBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes), new object[0]);
    private static ModuleBuilder AnonTypeMB;
    private static int AssemCount = 25;

    // create a pseudo anonymous type (POCO) from an IDictionary of property names and values
    // using public fields instead of properties
    // no methods are defined on the type
    public static Type MakeAnonymousType(IDictionary<string, Type> objDict) {
        // find or create AssemblyBuilder for dynamic assembly
        if (AnonTypeMB == null) {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName($"MyDynamicAssembly{AssemCount}");
            var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            AnonTypeMB = ab.DefineDynamicModule("MyDynamicModule");
        }
        // get a dynamic TypeBuilder
        var typeBuilder = AnonTypeMB.DefineType($"<>f__AnonymousType{AssemCount++}`{objDict.Keys.Count}", TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AutoLayout | TypeAttributes.NotPublic | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit);
        typeBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(CompilerGeneratedAttributeBuilder);

        // create generic parameters for every field
        string gtpName(string fieldName) => $"<{fieldName}>j__TPar";
        var gtpnames = objDict.Keys.Select(k => gtpName(k)).ToArray();
        var gtpbs = typeBuilder.DefineGenericParameters(gtpnames);
        var gtpN2Bs = gtpnames.Zip(gtpbs, (n, pb) => new { n, pb }).ToDictionary(g => g.n, g => g.pb);

        // add public fields to match the source object
        var fbs = new List<FieldBuilder>();
        foreach (var srcFieldName in objDict.Keys)
            fbs.Add(typeBuilder.DefineField(srcFieldName, gtpN2Bs[gtpName(srcFieldName)], FieldAttributes.Public));

        // Fix the generic class
        var fieldTypes = objDict.Values.ToArray();        
        return typeBuilder.CreateType().MakeGenericType(fieldTypes);
    }

    static string MakeAnonymousTypeKey(IDictionary<string, Type> objDict) => objDict.Select(d => $"{d.Key}~{d.Value}").Join("|");

    public static Dictionary<string, Type> PrevAnonTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    public static Type FindOrMakeAnonymousType(IDictionary<string, Type> objDict) {
        var wantedKey = MakeAnonymousTypeKey(objDict);
        if (!PrevAnonTypes.TryGetValue(wantedKey, out var newType)) {
            newType = MakeAnonymousType(objDict);
            PrevAnonTypes[wantedKey] = newType;
        }

        return newType;
    }    
}
```

And here is some sample code using it with a SQL Table named `Accounts` which has a class type named `Accounts`. Because my anonymous type doesn't have a constructor that takes the field values, I use a `MemberInitExpression` instead of the normal `NewExpression` (which seems unnecessarily complicated anyway?).

```
var objDescr = new Dictionary<string, Type> { { "Actid", typeof(Int32) }, { "Application", typeof(string) }, { "Username", typeof(string) }};
var aType = AnonymousExt.FindOrMakeAnonymousType(objDescr);

var parma = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Accounts), "a");
var fxbe = aType.GetFields().Select(fi => Expression.Bind(fi, Expression.Field(parma, fi.Name))).ToArray();
var mie = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(aType), fxbe);
var myf = Expression.Lambda<Func<Accounts, object>>(mie, parma);

var ans = Accounts.Select(myf).Take(2);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is a lot to take in so I'll have to dig in to individual items and read the API. Seems like initializing an anonymous object is way harder than I imagined. I'll check to see if there is a library for it.

Comment: @Help123 This is from code I already had implemented for the challenge :), from a lot of sources I pulled together. (Also, for interoperability between `DataTable`, `ExpandoObject` and anonymous types.) Note that [`System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) includes a more sophisticated system that more closely emulates compiler anonymous types with properties, a constructor and `GetHashCode`/`Equals` implemented in the DynamicClass and DynamicClassFactory files.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types are just types that C# builds for you at compile time. Instead of trying to build an anonymous type, how about returning an `object[]` for each row of your generated query. As a bonus, that reduces the complexity of dealing with the returned data.

```cs
List<string> properties = ... ;
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

var selectExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object[]>>(
    Expression.NewArrayInit(
        typeof(object),
        properties.Select(p =>
        {
            var ret = Expression.Property(parameter, p);
            if (ret.Type != typeof(object))
                ret = Expression.Convert(ret, typeof(object));
            return ret;
        })
    ),
    parameter);
```